# Angular: resolve rendering in subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to do some changes in the DOM when 'noRender' changes. 'noRender' hiding all DOM and it changes in the subscribe method. I tried with 'onChanges' - it didn't work. I decided to write the code inside the subscribe method, but the re-render is executed after the subscribe method is completed. How can solve it? Please help

```
this.http.post(Main.BASE_URL + StaticData.SIGN_URL, {})
  .subscribe((value: Response) => {
    this.noRender = false;
    if(document.querySelector('.steps-list-line')){
        (document.querySelector('.steps-list-line') as HTMLElement).style.width =
        (document.querySelector('.active') as HTMLElement).offsetWidth +
        (document.querySelector('.active') as HTMLElement).offsetLeft + 'px';
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: What are the changes you wanna do exactly ? And when ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Example 1

To detect a change in value in the `noRender` variable, you can change the type of this variable to `BehaviorSubject<boolean>`. Thanks to this you get the opportunity to subscribe to the data stream.

```js
export class SomeComponent{

    noRender = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor() {
        this.noRender.subscribe((newValue) => {
            // handle value changed
        });
    }

    someAction() {
        // change value of the noRender subject
        this.noRender.next(true);
    }

}
```

#### Example 2

If the `noRender` variable is an input property, you can use a `property-watch-decorator` (link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/property-watch-decorator), which allows to detect changes in the input properties.

```js
export class SomeComponent{

    @OnChange(function(this: SomeComponent, newValue: boolean){
        // handle value changed
    })
    @Input() noRender: boolean;

}
```

Comment: The fact is that there is ngif in html, which depends on the 'noRender' parameter. The Subscribe method executes before re-rendering. Therefore, it is not possible to make changes to the DOM inside subscribe. In your opinion, how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Instead of doing the subsciption in the constructor, you can use an [Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), which will automatically subscribe to that subject and automatically update the template if the new value will be emitted. Example: `<div *ngIf="noRender | async"></div>`

Comment: I need the following sequence:
    1. The noRender parameter changes
    2. Re-render has occurred due to the change of the noRender parameter
    3. I did changes to the DOM with javascript

    I don’t know at what moment to execute point 3, since in the above moments when changing noRender, the subscribe method is first executed, and then re-rednering occurs.